# LINQ to XML updates - how does it handle multiple concurrent readers/writers?

Tags: linq, concurrency, linq-to-xml, updates

I have an old system that uses XML for it's data storage. I'm going to be using the data for another mini-project and wanted to use LINQ to XML for querying/updating the data; but there's 2 scenarios that I'm not sure whether I need to handle myself or not:

1- If I have something similar to the following code, and 2 people happen to hit the Save() at the same time?  Does LINQ to XML wait until the file is available again before saving, or will it just throw? I don't want to put locks in unless I need to :)

```
// I assume the next line doesn't lock the file
XElement doc = XElement.Load("Books.xml");
XElement newBook = new XElement("Book",
new XAttribute("publisher", "My Publisher"),
new XElement("author", "Me")));
doc.Add(newBook);

// What happens if two people try this at the same time?
doc.Save("Books.xml");
```

2- If I Load() a document, add a entry under a particular node, and then hit Save(); what happens if another user has already added a value under that node (since I hit my Load()) or even worse, deleted the node?

Obviously I can workaround these issues, but I couldn't find any documentation that could tell me whether I have to or not, and the first one at least would be a bit of a pig to test reliably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a LINQ to XML issue, but a basic concurrency issue.

1. Assuming the two people are hitting Save at the same time, and the backing store is a file, then depending on how you opened the file for saving, you might get an error.  If you leave it to the XDocument class (by just passing in a file name), then chances are it is opening it exclusively, and someone else trying to do the same (assuming the same code hitting it) will get an exception.  You basically have to synchronize access to any shared resource that you are reading from/writing to.
2. If another user has already added a value, then assuming you don't have a problem obtaining the resource to write to, your changes will overwrite the resource.  This is a frequent issue with databases known as optimistic concurrency, and you need some sort of value to indicate whether a change has occurred between the time you loaded the data, and when you save it (most databases will generate timestamp values for you).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'd argue it was a LINQ to XML issue as the other times I use LINQ the backend database takes care of such things.. I was just curious if there was any "magic" in LINQ to XML or not.

Comment: @Steve: Not at all.  It's really about concurrency to the file (I'm assuming this is the shared resource).  LINQ to XML doesn't do anything special for you in this case.